# Overriding java library classes with maven assembly plugin

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to extend an existing, closed-source product, by decompiling and rewriting some feature to fit my need (basically, a dark mode, to spare my eyes).

It works all fine when I launch from the IDE, because the IDE can make my own classes, with the same names and everything, override the ones in the jars I depend on with maven, probably by ordering the classpath correctly.

Now I'd like to make it self runnable to not have to use IntelliJ each time to launch my little hack, but the assembly:single maven task seems to refuse to add my classes over the exploded dependencies, with the following: `already added, skipping`.

How can I reverse this order, or allow overwriting, without having to decompile each and every class and ditch the original jar ?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer reading the source code of Plexus Archiver at [AbstractArchiver.java](https://github.com/sonatype/plexus-archiver/blob/b174ef5d935c94fe58da2b48913fde1f2b972a97/src/main/java/org/codehaus/plexus/archiver/AbstractArchiver.java)

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>MyLittleLaucher</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        <archiverConfig>
            <duplicateBehavior>add</duplicateBehavior>
        </archiverConfig>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

It is important to use version 3.4.2 because the default version is buggy (2.2-beta5), and then you can use `<duplicateBehavior>add</duplicateBehavior>` to force the files to overwrite. It now works perfectly.

Comment: Really suggesting a [version which is more than 12 years old](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-assembly-plugin). I strongly recommend to check this: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/ If you are using "default" version you should change your setup because that means you never defined the plugin versions... Please do so...

Comment: I updated to 3.4.2, which also works. How does maven choose default versions ?